# Adding files to bundle on meteor build

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor project, and I'd like to add a few bash scripts to the top directory in the bundle.tgz

I'm currently creating my bundle via: 
`meteor build bundle.tgz`

Is there a way to configure the build so that it would include those bash scripts on the top of the resulted tgz file?

Comment: Isn't that unnecessarily painful? Why not just write a wrapper script that does the build, and then adds the additional scripts manually to the result tgz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Create a bundling script

Create a file in the root directory of your project, `create_bundle.sh`, also add in your other scripts to the root directory of your project. I've used the example of one file, **some_file.sh**, add any more as you need

**create_bundle.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f bundle.tar.gz
rm -rf /tmp/bundle
meteor build /tmp/bundle
tar -xzf /tmp/bundle/*.tar.gz -C /tmp/bundle

## Add any more as needed
cp some_file.sh /tmp/bundle/bundle

rm /tmp/bundle/*.tar.gz
tar -cvzf bundle.tar.gz -C /tmp/bundle .
```

Now if you run `./create_bundle.sh` instead of `meteor build bundle.tar.gz` it will:

- Create a bundle.tar.gz in your project directory
- The bundle.tar.gz will have *some_file.sh* added to it too in the bundle folder. You can move this to the root folder by altering the `cp` line in the create_bundle.sh to use `/tmp/bundle/` instead of `/tmp/bundle/bundle`

### Alternative Modify the Meteor source

One option would be to git clone the meteor source

```
git clone http://github.com/meteor/meteor
```

Edit the file meteor/tools/bundler.js (at this point: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/f59380a6cfb1d09a6d8ef9abda11646d37e37356/tools/bundler.js#L1910)

and add in your batch file

```
builder.write('yourfile.sh', { data: new Buffer(
    "#!/bin/sh
    "echo 'hello world'\n", 'utf8')});
});
```

You can then build your project with this special build of meteor:

From your project directory (*nix):

```
/path/to/cloned_meteor_repo/meteor build yourfile.tar.gz
```

Comment: I ended up creating a bundling script. I would also recommend using `meteor build --directory .` so it builds a directory and there's no need to extract the tar.gz

Comment: Woah, editing the source of Meteor is kind of a desperate solution!

Comment: yeah I'd consider flipping those, because the bundling seems more appropriate